# Hyperlinks do not get proper value

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that has an infinite loop in it. The browser does not print the first echo statements in the loop, it does not even provide proper links to the hyperlinks. What could have gone wrong?

[Demo](http://directory.ligerlabs.com/)

### Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
img{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
error_reporting (0);
set_time_limit(0);// Setting an infinite timeout limit.
        for($i=1;  ;$i++)
            {
            $to_send = "http://graph.facebook.com/";
            $to_send_new = $to_send.$i;
            $content = file_get_contents($to_send_new);
            $parsed = json_decode($content);
            $link = $parsed->link;
            $link = str_replace("http://www.facebook.com","https://graph.facebook.com",$link);
            $link .="/picture?width=200&height=200";
            if(!$parsed->first_name)
            goto a;
?>

<br>
            First Name: <?php echo $parsed->first_name;?>
            <br>
            Last Name:<?php echo $parsed->last_name;?>
            <br>
            Full Name :<?php echo $parsed->name;?>
            <br>
            Facebook Username:<?php echo $parsed->username;?>
            <br>
            Gender:<?php echo $parsed->gender;?>
            <br>

            <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_blank">Profile Picture</a> 
            <!--
             <img src="<?php/* echo $link; */?>" >
             -->
             <br>
             <hr>

 <?php

        sleep(5);
a:
 }

 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am getting a feeling it is happening due to the server overload.

Comment: I can see the names, and the hyperlink to the profile image just fine (First one is Mark Zuckerberg), or am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [For loop does not work more than 43 times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206690/for-loop-does-not-work-more-than-43-times)

Comment: @Dogbert: Some of the links generated do not get the actual domain name in them.

Comment: Why does the first profile picture hyperlink lead to http://directory.ligerlabs.com/picture?width=200&height=200 ???

Comment: Why are you deliberately creating an infinite loop?

Comment: try to var_dump($parsed) or print_r($parsed) first.

Comment: @desbest: That is the question I asked here. Its weird.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with infinite loops. Depending on your web server (eg. apache) and php settings any request to your server adds up a thread on the server, which eats their set of ressources. This may or may not hang up your server over time.

Sometimes I use long lasting loops myself. In such cases I found apachestatus useful, to check which threads are still running:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html

It also provides the PID which helps to kill old threads.